# Some field collection items not editable by admin

Tags: entities

My Drupal site has developed a very strange problem. For some reason I cannot edit field collection items of certain sites on their own edit URL, but others work fine.

For example:

/field-collection/field-collecton-type-a/1/edit   <-- Works fine, displays a form and I can edit the item

/field-collection/field-collecton-type-b/2/edit   <-- Displays "Access denied: You are not authorized to access this page."

There are no obvious differences between the field collection items. Sometime I have even noticed that within one particular type of field collection, an individual item can sometimes be edited and at other times it can't.

I have tried the following:

- Clear the cache completely many times
- I am logged in as admin, but just in case I completely rebuilt the permissions and gave admin access to everything
- Exported the field collection using Features and then re-imported it

Really scratching my head with this, and would appreciate any suggestions as to what to try next.

Comment: I just had this same issue and I found that the field collections were flagged as archived if I looked at the field collection table.  Resetting in the database restored the links.

Comment: @Brent how did you do that?

Comment: In field_collection_item reset the archived bit to 0.  To find archived records:
`SELECT * FROM field_collection_item WHERE archived = 1;`

To update:
`UPDATE field_collection_item SET archived = 0 WHERE archived = 1;`